# How to configure jenkins with titanium studio to work?

Tags: android, titanium, jenkins-plugins

I want to develop a mobile application with titanium. Before starting I should first configure SVN and jenkins with titanium studio. I have already installed a plugin svn: subversion plugin on jenkins server plus another plugin named Eclipse plugin on titanium studio. Now I want to configure titanium with jenkins. I searched jenkins plugins available and I found a plugin called: android lint plugin.

Is what I must also  install it?

Answer (score 5):

1. Configure your repository in jenkins (SVN, git..) and [install the Titanium CLI](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_the_Titanium_CLI).
2. Add a buildstep to the Jenkins buildprocess for this project, which invokes a script in the Titanium folder. Perhaps you need to unlock your mac keychain before starting that build script, for more information have a look at http://www.egeek.me/2013/02/23/jenkins-and-xcode-user-interaction-is-not-allowed/ . If you combine the call of the build script with the unlocking, everything will run fine automatically.
3. The build.sh contains the call for the Titanium CLI:

   ```
   titanium build --force --developer-name "YOURDEVNAME" --pp-uuid "YOURUUID" --platform ios --build-only --target device --device-family universal
   ```

   This will build the project and create a .ipa in the folder build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/